# How to toggle bars when checkbox is checked without js

Tags: html, css, checkbox

how to toggle it , it is not working , i want to transform the bar. when checkbox is checked.

```
<div class="bars">  <input type="checkbox" id="menuToggle"/>
            <label for="menuToggle" class="menu-icon">
        <span class="bar-1"></span>
        <span class="bar-2"></span>
        <span class="bar-3"></span>
</label>
    </div>
```

here is css

```
.menu-icon .bar-1,.menu-icon .bar-2,.menu-icon .bar-3{display:block;background:#000;height:4px;margin:4px 0;width:30px;transition:0.5s ease;}
```

this for checked box

```
#menuToggle:checked ~ .menu-icon .bar-1 {transform:rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px,3px);-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px,3px)}
 #menuToggle:checked ~ .menu-icon .bar-2 {opacity:0;}
 #menuToggle:checked ~ .menu-icon .bar-3 {transform:rotate(45deg) translate(-8px,-3px);-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) translate(-8px,-3px);}
```

It is not working please tell me the steps how it works :D

Answer (score 0):

Just change the label to div and remove the for.

```
<div class="bars">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menuToggle" />
  <div class="menu-icon">
    <span class="bar-1"></span>
    <span class="bar-2"></span>
    <span class="bar-3"></span>
  </div>
</div>

.menu-icon .bar-1,
  .menu-icon .bar-2,
  .menu-icon .bar-3 {
    display: block;
    background: #000;
    height: 4px;
    margin: 4px 0;
    width: 30px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
  }

  #menuToggle:checked ~ .menu-icon .bar-1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 3px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 3px);
  }
  #menuToggle:checked ~ .menu-icon .bar-2 {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  #menuToggle:checked ~ .menu-icon .bar-3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -3px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -3px);
  }
  #menuToggle:checked ~ .menu-icon {
    visibility: visible;
  }
```